# ng-bootstrap datepicker multi-select of dates ( separated dates not in range selection )

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

bootstarp v 6.0.2 with angular 9 and i'm trying to do multiple select of date in datepicker like in this photo ?
actually i have this code allowing simple select of one date ?
did any body have an idea how can i do this ?

**datepicker.component.ts**

````
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  date: NgbDate | null;
  @Output() selectedDateEventEmitter = new EventEmitter<NgbDate>();
  @Input() minDate;
  @Input() maxDate;
  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    this.date = date;
    this.selectedDateEventEmitter.emit(date);
  }

  isWeekend(date: NgbDateStruct) {
    const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
    return d.getDay() === 0 || d.getDay() === 6;
  }

  isDisabled = (date: NgbDateStruct, current: { month: number }) => {
    const d = new Date(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day);
    return this.isWeekend(date); // this is undefined
  }
}```

**datepicker.component.html**

    <ngb-datepicker class="datepicker-custom"
                [(ngModel)]="date"
                [dayTemplate]="dayTemplate"
                [minDate]="minDate"
                [maxDate]="maxDate"
                [markDisabled]="isDisabled"
                (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"></ngb-datepicker>
<ng-template #dayTemplate let-date let-currentMonth="currentMonth" let-selected="selected" let-disabled="disabled" let-focused="focused">
  <div ngbdatepickerdayview class="custom-day btn-light"[class.weekend]="isWeekend(date)" [class.focused]="focused" [class.bg-primary.text-white]="selected" [class.hidden]="date.month !== currentMonth" [class.text-muted]="disabled">
    <span>{{ date.day }}</span>
  </div>
</ng-template>
````

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: i want to have multiple selection of dates an got the as output instead of having one 
 selected date

Comment: something like this?. `https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#multidate`

Comment: yeah but using ng-bootstrap not bootstrap

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.